# Cannot access SFTP/Webserver with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2017, sftp

After using Notepad++ to develop a website for a while now, I decided to try a more advanced IDE and installed Visual Studio.
In NPP I used the NppFTP plugin to work on my webserver and never had problems doing so. But when I try to acces my code with Visual Studio, weird things happen.
So I click on "Open Website" on the Start Page.
There I select FTP. 
When I fill in the same server, port and login data, which still works in Npp, I get an error saying "Rebex FTP/SSL does not support SFTP/SSH protocol.

When I write sftp://aiatlas055.cern.ch instead of aiatlas055.cern.ch, Visual Studio displays an empty dark blue page and starts lagging and being unresponsive.

Can anybody tell my what is the proper way to connect to my webserver ?

Comment: just develop locally and then deploy

Comment: This would be very inconvenient.
In Npp, I just press ctrl + s and then reload the website in the browser and can test the changes immediately.
Is Visual Studio really not able to provide the same workflow ?

Comment: do you edit live website? it's a bad practice. You need to develop it locally, test using IIS express (embedded in VS) and then deploy using web deploy or ftp.

Comment: There are no active users yet on my website and I did not know it was possible to run a website locally without a remote server.
But thanks, I will try that, but I think Visual Studio is way too complicated for me and I will stick to Npp now.
Did not expect to run into such difficulties.

Comment: if VS is too complex for you  you can try VS Code: https://code.visualstudio.com/